How do I manage socket.io connections between multiple tabs of the same application?
TLDR
I'm trying to understand how sockets behave between tabs and how to not have two connections at the same time on two different tabs for the same application.
I have a React application. When I successfully log into my application, I hit a useEffect which establishes a socket connection. This is in my routes component.
useEffect() => {
    if (auth) {
      socketService.connect();
      socketService.onMessage(...callback function)
    }
  }, [auth]);

I then need to navigate to another component within this application, but I can only do so via url (there is no internal navigation on purpose).
When I do this, I need to be hooked up to the onMessage callback above as well as join a room / listen for messages in this new component.
Component via URL navigation:
useEffect(() => {
**ISSUE: this room is never joined, because no socketService connection is established in this new tab. Why?**
    socketService.joinRoom(windowQueueRoom);
    socketService.onMessage(...callback function);
  }, []);

If I socketService.connect() in this (^) useEffect, a second connection is established in addition to the connection established in my routes file.

and how to not have two connections at the same time on two different tabs Thats not how it works. You establish for each tab a connection.
